# Как составить запрос, что бы в один подход получить данные?

Tags: mysql

Возможно ли составить такой запрос, что бы в один подход получить данные? Чтобы он не выполнял несколько раз меняя только цифру месяца, а выдавал количество записей для каждого?

```
SELECT
  COUNT(name) AS jun
FROM
  calendar
WHERE
  month = 6;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Думаю вот так

```
SELECT
  COUNT(name) AS cnt,
  month AS month
FROM
  calendar
GROUP BY
  month;
```

И добавить `WHERE` если нужно.